# Scrape a JavaScript heavy website with requests+bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some data on a [stock market](https://www.cse.lk/). But I don't like to use selenium. I always trace the fetch requests and use the requests module.

On this site, I found the URLs which I think as responsible for fetching data to the frontend.

[image: example image]

But those links can't be accessed directly ex:[link](https://www.cse.lk/api/marketSummery). They throw HTTP 405. Why is that?

Comment: You don't, you need something which understands Javascript but requests and bs4 do not

Comment: you cannot access this URL direct as it can be queried through api with POST request.

Comment: @MichaelRuth I'm not going to request the main URL but instead, I use the API endpoint  URLs to retrieve the JSON data I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the API by making a POST request.

Try this:

```
import requests
response = requests.post('https://www.cse.lk/api/marketSummery')
json.loads(response.content)
```

Output

```
{'id': 30071974,
 'tradeVolume': 5829973145.4,
 'shareVolume': 231803649,
 'tradeDate': 1660549800496}
```

The other APIs work too, eg. this:

```
url = " https://www.cse.lk/api/dailyMarketSummery"
response = requests.post(url)
json.loads(response.content)
```

Output

```
[[{'id': 12893,
   'tradeDate': 1660501800000,
   'marketTurnover': 5829973000.0,
   'marketTrades': 51086.0,
   'marketDomestic': 50376.0,
   'marketForeign': 710.0,
   'equityTurnover': 5829973000.0,
   'equityDomesticPurchase': 5709995000.0,
   'equityDomesticSales': 5592159700.0,
   'equityForeignPurchase': 119978192.0,
   'equityForeignSales': 237813568.0,
   'volumeOfTurnOverNumber': 231803648.0,
   'volumeOfTurnoverDomestic': 226246512.0,
   'volumeOfTurnoverForeign': 5320827,
   'tradesNo': 51086,
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    r = requests.post(url)
    pp(r.json())


main('https://www.cse.lk/api/marketSummery')
```

```
{'id': 30071974,
 'tradeVolume': 5829973145.4,
 'shareVolume': 231803649,
 'tradeDate': 1660549800496}
```